# How to import in format CSV chars as in Local regional language PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10

I want to upload a CSV file with having regional language character in some of values , e.g. if format is like

```
FirstName,LastName,DOB,State
Rahul,Gour,25-Mar-1988,Delhi
രാഹുൽ,ഗൗർ,24-മാർ-1987,Kerala
```

in above format some line exists with loacal langauge (Malyalam) when i uploading this file data where this speical charater showing data as "????????????

Is there any format i can use to upload this data as it is , or we cannot be do this in PostgreSQL.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to figure out what kind of encoding the CSV file uses. Most probably it is using the UTF-8 encoding. Afterwards you can just use:

```
copy tablename (firstname, lastname, dob, state)
from /path/to/the/file.csv
with (encoding 'UTF-8', format csv);
```

If the server doesn't have access to the file you can use the equivalent `\copy` command for psql.